# Q tips on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Is it permissible to use q tips on shabbat? The cotton devices used to remove ear wax.  What are the possible issues involved?

Comment: [MedicineNet.com](http://www.medicinenet.com/ear_wax/page3.htm) says

Is it OK to use Q-tips?

Most attempts to clean the ears by using cotton swabs only result in pushing the wax further into the ear canal. ...Q-Tips, bobby pins or twisted napkin corners only serve as ramrods to push the wax deeper into the ear and can lead to problems.

Comment: How does that answer the halachic question in any shape or form?

Comment: You're right - it does not. But it does say that the procedure is medically not advised.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5774/noach.html

Shemiras Shabbos k’Hilchasah 32:59 says there is no problem using a cotton swab on Shabbos. Harav A. Weiss, published in Ohr ha-Shabbos, vol. 18, pgs. 22-23 also permits using a cotton swab on Shabbos, however Orchos Shabbos 13:45 who does not permit using cotton swabs on Shabbos.

> Question: On Shabbos or Yom Tov, is it permitted to use a cotton swab
>   (Q-tip) to dab hydrogen peroxide, etc., on a cut or an abrasion?
>
> Discussion: Based on the previous Discussion, there is no reason to
>   prohibit using cotton swabs on Shabbos. Although it is forbidden to
>   soak a cotton ball (or a piece of cotton batting) and then squeeze the
>   liquid out of it, 5 this does not apply to using a swab. The small
>   piece of pressed cotton at the swab’s end is not meant to absorb, nor
>   is the liquid “squeezed” out of it. When used normally, the tip merely
>   transfers the liquid to the cut without any squeezing taking place. It
>   is permitted to be used. 6 Obviously, though, in the atypical case
>   where the swab is used in a manner which would result in squeezing, it
>   would be forbidden to use it on Shabbos.

Comment: Aren't they speaking about putting it into liquids?  Would the same apply to ear wax?

Comment: @AaronMiller All you asked about above was using a Q-tip. If you wish to ask about a specific use for it, I recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: Ostensibly wax shouldn't be any worse than the other applications